# Shapely import error: No module named 'shapely'

Tags: python, shapely

I've installed `shapely` with `pip install shapely` and importing it as `from shapely.geometry import Point`. I get this error:

```
  from shapely.geometry import Point
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shapely'
```

I'm n MacOS High Sierra. All other installed python libraries work like a charm. I'm new to Python so forgive me in advance.
I've read several similar questions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19279656/cannot-import-shapely-ubuntu-python)) but none seemed to solve my problem.

Comment: Did you `pip install` it to a virtual environment? If so, you need to activate your virtual environment with `source myvenv/bin/activate`. If you haven't set up a virtual environment yet, you might have installed the module in the wrong directory. Make sure to install the module into the main directory of your project.

Comment: Where did `pip` install it, and what is the value of `sys.path`?

Comment: You might find this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35017160/how-to-use-virtualenv-with-python) useful, as it provides resources on how to use a virtual environment. Virtual environments help you manage project dependencies and is especially helpful when you have multiple projects.

Comment: @JohnGordon I installed it in my home directory  `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`. How do I check the value of my `sys.path`?

Comment: @JackMoody is there a way to install it globally for any projects? How do I activate the env?

Comment: @Daniela normally you don't want to install a module globally, because you will probably use multiple versions of the same module in between your projects. If you really do want to install it globally, you can use `sudo` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936212/how-do-i-install-a-pip-package-globally-instead-of-locally/36937521). However, I would strongly encourage using a virtual environment if you plan on having multiple projects in the future.

Comment: @JackMoody Thank you. I'll look into it.

Comment: `import sys; print (sys.path)`

Answer (score 12):

Run the following command in activated *virtualenv*:

```
pip install shapely
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this command and it was efficient.

```
conda install -c conda-forge shapely
```